# Is Israel considering to join Operation Prosperity Guardian?

Tags: israel, houthi-movement

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Prosperity_Guardian

> United States Secretary of Defense Lloyd Austin announced the
> formation of an international maritime security force, which aims to
> end the Houthi blockade of Israel in the Red Sea[3] and counter
> threats by Houthi forces against international maritime commerce
> heading or related to Israel[4] following weeks of attacks against
> commercial vessels amid the 2023 Israel–Hamas war and Houthi
> involvement in it.[5][6] The coalition currently has more than 20
> members.[7] Egypt and Saudi Arabia, both economically reliant on
> unhindered commercial shipping in the area, are absent from the listed
> participants.[8] The chairman of the Suez Canal Authority, Usama
> Rabia, stated that "Navigation traffic in the Suez Canal was not
> affected by what is happening in the Red Sea".[9] In addition to the
> eleven listed coalition members, ten governments are anonymously
> involved.[10]

Is Israel considering to join Operation Prosperity Guardian? Considering that Israel is the country most affected, or one of the most affected countries in this blockade, I was surprised that Israel is not at all involved in this operation when countries like Greece and Seychelles are belligerent in this operation against the Houthis. Did Israel show any interest or made any public statement about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assert,

> Israel is not at all involved

But there is no evidence for this assertion.

The Wikipedia page you quoted already states,

> ten governments are anonymously involved

More on this:

*Reuters* ([2023-12-21](https://www.reuters.com/world/more-than-20-countries-now-part-us-led-red-sea-coalition-pentagon-2023-12-21/)):

> A total of more than 20 countries have agreed to participate ...
>
> at least eight of the countries who have signed up have also declined to be publicly named ...
>
> "We've had over 20 nations now sign on to participate," Major General Patrick Ryder said, noting declarations by Greece and Australia.
>
> "We'll allow other countries, defer to them to talk about their participation."

White House Press Briefing ([2023-12-19](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/12/19/press-briefing-by-press-secretary-karine-jean-pierre-and-nsc-coordinator-for-strategic-communications-john-kirby-34/)):

> Q    And one more question.  There are some unnamed countries that are currently involved in the Red Sea initiative.  Can you say more about why those countries don’t want to be named?  And is it a sign that, you know, countries don’t want to be seen standing with the United States at this moment, you know, in the region?
>
> MR. KIRBY: There are some nations that have agreed to participate and to be a part of this, but they get to decide — they’re sovereign nations — they get to decide how public they want that to be.  And I’ll leave it up to them to be able to describe it one way or another since — because not all want to become public.  I doubt you’re going to get much — much more out of them

Altogether, 11 countries have been explicitly named by US officials as participating: Australia, the UK, Bahrain, Canada, France, Greece, Italy, the Netherlands, Norway, Seychelles, and Spain.

So, if Ryder's claim that "over 20 nations" are participating is true, then there are at least 10 more countries, one of which may or may not be Israel.