# What was India's response to alleged Iranian attack on a ship off her coast?

Tags: international-relations, india, iran, drones

Recently, there was a drone attack on a ship off India's coast on the Arabian Sea.

The US has said that this attack was carried out from Iranian soil. Iran has denied these allegations.
[[Source](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/12/25/iran-dismisses-us-claim-it-hit-tanker-near-india)]

What was India's (official or unofficial) response to this incident?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83455/is-israel-considering-to-join-operation-prosperity-guardian https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83045/why-are-there-so-few-reactions-to-the-houthis-attacks-on-ships

Comment: Also the ship was struck some 200 miles "off coast", as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, some Indian politicians [have](https://news.usni.org/2023/12/26/india-vows-vengeance-after-merchant-vessel-attacks) been a bit more adamant than what Brian's answer suggests:

> India’s Defense Minister Raksha Mantri Shri Rajnath Singh promised retribution for these attacks during the commissioning ceremony of INS Imphal (D68), the Indian Navy’s third Visakhapatnam-class destroyer.
>
> **“Those who have carried out these attacks, we will find them from the bottom of the sea, and strict action will be taken against them,” said Shri Rajnath Singh.**
>
> The defense minister emphasized India’s role as the “Net Security Provider in the entire Indian Ocean Region” and commitment to keeping the sea lanes open for greater regional trade in collaboration with international partners. [...]
>
> Chief of the Naval Staff Adm. R Hari Kumar highlighted India’s commitment to keeping the sea lanes open. While it is not known if India is participating in U.S.-led Operation Prosperity Guardian, New Delhi has deployed a number of its assets in the Red and Arabian Seas.
>
> Kumar said since the crisis began the Indian Navy has deployed four Kolkata and Visakhapatnam destroyers to the area to counter further attacks on merchant vessels. Adm. Kumar also revealed that the Indian Navy’s American-built P-8I Poseiden and MQ-9B SeaGuardian aircraft have been deployed as well under efforts to boost surveillance.

From another [report](https://www.reuters.com/world/india/indian-navy-deploy-guided-missile-destroyer-ships-after-strike-off-its-coast-2023-12-26/):

> Prime Minister Narendra Modi's government had taken the drone attack on MV Chem Pluto and an earlier attack on commercial crude oil vessel MV Sai Baba, in the Red Sea, very seriously, Singh said.

Both ships were crewed by Indians and headed to India, [according](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/initial-assessment-of-merchant-vessel-chem-pluto-indicates-a-drone-attack-navy/article67674759.ece) to *The Hindu*, but there's been some dispute with the US whether one of them was also India flagged. (Indian Navy [said](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/25-indian-crew-onboard-mv-saibaba-oil-ship-attacked-by-houthi-drone-in-red-sea-navy-101703395232383.html) it wasn't.)

Answer (score 4):

[According to CNBC TV as of December 26, 2023](https://www.cnbctv18.com/photos/india/drone-strike-on-mv-chem-pluto-a-detailed-investigation-unfolds-18646301.htm) the Indian Navy's preliminary investigation results are inconclusive at this time and a more detailed study will be conducted. They have also increased their defenses in the area.